# Weird thing with scanning strings in c

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

I am aware that for scanning up to 4 chars you need to use `%4s`. As in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   char str0[4] = "123"; // 1 char for '\0'
   char str1[5]; // +1 char for \0
   printf("String str0 = '%s'\n", str0);
   printf("Enter 4 chars: ");
   scanf("%4s", str1);

   printf("You entered string '%s'\n", str1);
   printf("String str0 = '%s'\n", str0);
}
```

But I wonder, why changing `scanf("%4s", str1)` into `scanf("%s", str1)` results in this:

Input:

```
String str0 = '123'
Enter 4 chars: 123456789
```

Output:

```
You entered string '123456789'
String str0 = '6789'
```

Edit: I noticed that when using `#include <string.h>` the output is still `String str0 = '123'`.

Comment: Does it happen every single time you execute the program?

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. I noticed that I didn't mention that I am not using <string.h> Therefore I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *But I wonder, why changing `scanf("%4s", str1)` into `scanf("%s", str1)` results into this:* [...]

When you change your code and remove the width limit from `scanf` you allow it to write outside the bounds of the array. That is an example of [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), for that kind of construct there is no expected output, the compiler may deal with it in any way it sees fit.

For example, if I compile your code into two programs with the exact same compiler, ***gcc 10.2*** (including the header `<string.h>`), with and without optimization (`O3`), the runtime results for each program are different:

Input:

```
123456789
```

Outputs:

```
String str0 = '123'  // optimized
```

```
String str0 = '6789' // not optimized
```

As you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/WfGer47P6

---

> *I noticed that when using `#include <string.h>` the output is still `String str0 = '123'`*

Yet another symptom of undefined behavior.

Comment: Where does the UB come from? The scanf parameter is `%4s` so it should be in bounds.

Comment: @Devolus the OP then changed to `scanf("%s", str1);` and uses input `123456789`.